# Not saving the changes I make when I deselect Orders using checkboxes from an existing Delivery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, mvvm, saving-data

I'm having difficulty in `saving changes` I make to a existing `Delivery` on the `Edit Delivery` page when I try to `deselect` `Orders` that have already been linked to that `Delivery`.

I want to be able to `remove` those `Orders` I've already added when I initially `Created` the `Delivery` and `add` more based on the `Orders` available today and then save.

Currently, it doesn't save when I `deselect` the `Orders` that I have previously added through the `Create` method, so those `Orders` are still linked to the `Delivery`. However, it does allow me to add more `Orders` so that's alright.

So, essentially, the problem lies in the POST method of Edit.

Can anyone please advise me on a fix or a way forward? Thank you in advance.

**View Models:**

```
 public class DeliveryVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dispatched_Date { get; set; }
    public List<OrderVM> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class OrderVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryID { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

**Models:**

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int? DeliveryID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expected_Date { get; set; }
    public virtual Delivery Delivery { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class Delivery
{

    public int DeliveryID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dispatched_Date { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit Method in Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(DeliveryVM model)
{
    // Get the data model based on the ID of the view model
    Delivery delivery = db.Deliverys.Find(model.ID);
    // Map the view model properties to the data model
    delivery.DriverID = model.DriverID;
     ...
    // Mark as modified and save
    IEnumerable<int> selectedOrders = model.Orders.Where(o => o.IsSelected).Select(o => o.ID);
    foreach (int ID in selectedOrders)
    {
        Order order = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
        order.DeliveryID = delivery.DeliveryID;
        db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = delivery.DeliveryID });

}
```

Comment: Hey @StephenMuecke, would appreciate if you could have a look at this. It's based on `code` you've helped me with before so I think you'll understand this much better. This essentially works fine, except that it doesn't remove the `Order` when I deselect the `checkbox` it only allows me to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is only modifying the orders that have been selected in the `Edit` view, and unnecessarily updating orders that were previously selected.

You need to make a comparison with the original orders, and take the appropriate action

```
// Get the original selected orders
IEnumerable<int> originalOrders = delivery.Orders.Select(o => o.OrderID);
// Get the selected orders from the Edit view
IEnumerable<int> selectedOrders = model.Orders.Where(o => o.IsSelected).Select(o => o.ID);
// Get the orders that have been added
IEnumerable<int> newOrders = selectedOrders.Except(originalOrders);
// Get the orders that have been deleted
IEnumerable<int> deletedOrders = originalOrders.Except(selectedOrders);
foreach (int ID in newOrders)
{
  // Get the order, set its DeliveryID property and save (as per your existing code)
}
IEnumerable<Order> toDelete= db.Orders.Where(o => deletedOrders.Contains(o.OrderID));
foreach (Order order in toDelete)
{
  order.DeliveryID = null;
  db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Side note: There is no need to update items that have not changed, but if you wanted to get them, it would be

```
IEnumerable<int> unchangedOrders= originalOrders.Intersect(selectedOrders);
```

Comment: `foreach (int ID in deletedOrders)
            {
                Order order = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
                order.DeliveryID = null;
                db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }` That's the code I put for removing orders, and I get this error and it times out. An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code. It did remove the `Order`

Comment: Difficult to read you code in comments, but inside the loops you should make the change (set the `DeliveryID` value and set `EntityState.Modified` but call `db.SaveChanges()` after the loops

Comment: I edited your answer with the code inside, so that you can have a proper look. I do call `db.SaveChanges();` and `EntityState.Modified`

Comment: I have updated your edit to put the `db.SaveChanges();` after the loops.

Comment: Hmmm, now that same error appears to sit on the `foreach` in `foreach (int ID in deletedOrders)`. To be more specific, the error says that `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute`.

Comment: Not sure I understand the error message, but I'll update teh answer with a more efficient way of dong this anyway (need a break for 10 minutes)

Comment: I updated accordingly but it now has a problem with this line `db.Orders.Where(deletedOrders.Contains(o => o.OrderID));` - it says it doesn't contain a definition for where and and best extension overload.

Comment: Error: `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<HealthHabitat.Models.Order>`  does not contain a definition for `Where` and the best extension method overload `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>  (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, SystemFunc<TSource,int,bool>)` has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the only or best way but in the past when I have a selection I find the easiest way is to deselect everything 1st, then save changes, then add the new ones and then save again.

So something like:

```
var oldOrders = deliver.Orders.ToList();

foreach(var o in oldOrders)
{
   delivery.Orders.Remove(o);
}
db.SaveChanges();

//  now add the new orders
```

UPDATE:
Just thought I would add that the reason you probably having issues deleting is if you try delete a record and then add it before saving changes has caused issues for me in the past.

Also I find materialising the list with ToList before avoids issues with trying to change a collection that is constantly changing.